# Unexpectedly moved decimal points in C++

Tags: c++

This is my first ever post in stackoverflow. I am currently relearning C++, and I am having trouble understanding what is happening in the process of unexpected changed value of the variable double userBase[j].height in this system.

As you can see in this first photo, everything seems to be working fine:
[image]

Now, every time I want to print out a table of all collected information from the 5 array of struct, the values for the height suddenly changed and it moved 2 decimal points.
[image]

I am currently figuring out where the problem is coming from.. I am suspecting it came from the setprecision() but I do not know how it happened.

### **My Source Code:**

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

const int size = 5;

struct users{

    double height, ft, in, weight, age;
    double bmi;
    int bmiLevel;
    string gender;
};

int main(){


users userBase[size];

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){

    cout << "Enter your weight (lbs): ";
    cin  >> userBase[i].weight;
    userBase[i].weight = userBase[i].weight*0.453592;


    cout << "Enter your height (feet): ";
    cin  >> userBase[i].ft;
    cout << "Enter your height (inches): ";
    cin  >> userBase[i].in;
    userBase[i].ft = userBase[i].ft * 30.48;
    userBase[i].in = userBase[i].in * 2.54;
    userBase[i].height = userBase[i].ft + userBase[i].in;

    cout << "\n\n\nheight and weight are converted to kilograms and centimeters respectively \n\n";

    cout << "Weight: " << userBase[i].weight << " kg" << endl;
    cout << "Height: " << userBase[i].height << " cm" << endl;

    userBase[i].height = userBase[i].height * 0.01;
    userBase[i].bmi = userBase[i].weight / (userBase[i].height*userBase[i].height);
    cout << "Your Body Mass Index (BMI): " << userBase[i].bmi << endl;

    if(userBase[i].bmi<18){
        cout << "Underweight! ";
    }
    if(userBase[i].bmi>18 && userBase[i].bmi<25){
        cout << "Ideal";
    }
    if(userBase[i].bmi>25 && userBase[i].bmi<30){
        cout << "Overweight";
    }
    if(userBase[i].bmi>30){
        cout <<"Obese";
    }
    system("CLS");
    }


    cout<<left<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
         cout<<"Weight         Height        BMI       Status \n";
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){

             cout<<setw(0)<<userBase[j].weight
                 <<setw(10)<<"kg"
                 <<setw(0)<<userBase[j].height
                 <<setw(10)<<"cm"
                 <<setw(10)<<userBase[j].bmi;

    if(userBase[j].bmi<18){
        cout << "Underweight! ";
    }
    if(userBase[j].bmi>18 && userBase[j].bmi<25){
        cout << "Ideal";
    }
    if(userBase[j].bmi>25 && userBase[j].bmi<30){
        cout << "Overweight";
    }
    if(userBase[j].bmi>30){
        cout <<"Obese";
    }
    cout << endl;
             }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out this one for about an hour now, and any help given to this post will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text into the question, *as text*, instead.

Comment: As for the decimal-point problem, you *do* know what [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is supposed to do?

Comment: Lastly about the other problem, now is a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the help! I apologize if this post was some sort of 'help me debug my program'. Clearly, learning how to debug your own program is an invaluable skill. Thanks for showing me the way :))

Answer (score 3):

I found out where the problem is coming from:

in the middle of the code, I multiplied the values for all the height to 0.01 which made it moved two decimal points when printing out the table.

the solution I made was to multiply it back to 100 to get the original height in cm.

Thank you, @someprogrammerdude for your advice!

Comment: Don't convert the data in place, as you will keep getting bugs like that. Define each field (e.g. by a comment) as containing multiples of a certain unit. If you need a different unit for a calculation, introduce a new local variable for the conversion. E.g., right now, you also modify `ft` in place by multiplying it by 30.48. Now, it doesn't contain feet anymore but the number of feet converted into cm, which is confusing. Instead, you could create a local variable `const auto ft_in_cm = ft * 30.48`, or just do `height = ft * 30.48 + in * 2.54`. (Use named constants, too, however.)

Comment: I completely agree with you.. It is a bad practice to convert data in place..as
 seen earlier it costed me an hour trying to fix the bug. In comparison, if I just created a constant local variable, it could have saved me time. Thank you for the lesson! I'll start applying that right now